# Google rich snippet not showing "free" tag for "Offer"

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have added structured data for `AggregateRating` and `Offer` on my page. However, in Google Search it shows the rich snippet with rating only, the offer i.e. 'free' tag is not shown.

It shows all good in Google Structured Data Testing Tool, but in Google Search results it does not show the results it suppose to be.

JSON-LD code snippet:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "Trading using Options Sentiment Indicators",
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.49",
    "reviewCount": 39
  },
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "INR",
    "price": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you see this rich result for any other site? Or did you find Google’s documentation about it?

Comment: @unor Google's documentation about rich result [link](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products)

Comment: But on the Products rich result documentation, they don’t mention/show that it’s supported for gratis products, do they? I just wonder if this is maybe something that only the SDTT shows in its preview … do you know a live example for a page which shows "free" or similar in the rich result?

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Comment: @unor [this](https://www.weltpixel.com/magento2-google-rich-cards-free-extension.html) is the live example for page which shows 'free' tag using product.

Comment: Could it be the missing quotation marks at the numbers? `"0"` instead of `0`?

Answer (score 1):

For the specified webpage, you used property to **Product**. But this webpage offers free courses. Therefore, I recommend that you apply markup to property **[Course](http://schema.org/Course)**. To mark the free cost, you can apply an element **[isAccessibleForFree](http://schema.org/isAccessibleForFree)**. Also, I recommend that you apply more detailed structured data to mark out your courses. For example, you missed the markup with with an important element **[description](http://schema.org/description)**. In this property there are many more elements that are great for marking the specified webpage.

Comment: If i used **Course** i only can give three properties i.e. name, description and provider [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/courses) for course.